# Fourier coefficients implies absolutely continuity

Tags: sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

When I read some paper, it says

> $u\in H^{3/2}$ if and only if $u$ is absolutely continuous with $u'\in H^{1/2}$, where
> $$H^s=\left\{ u\in L^1(\mathbb{S}^1):\|u\|_{H^{s}} \doteq\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}|n|^{2 s}\left|a_{n}(u)\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right\}, a_{n}(u)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} {u}(e^{i\theta}) e^{-i n \theta} d \theta.$$

"If part" is easy to understand, but how to prove if $u\in H^{3/2}$, $u$ is absolutely continuous?

Any hint will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The absolute continuous part of the assertion is somewhat useless, it is just here to say that u' makes sense for people who do not know distribution theory.

Nevertheless your question boils down to the fact that $H^{3/2}$ is imbedded into absolutely continuous functions. The proof depends on how you define $H^{3/2}$. If for example you  follow the definition with Fourier coefficients, then you can check that
$v=\sum ina_ne^{inx}$ is an $L^2$ function (this is true even in $H^1$), and that actually $u-\int_0^x v$ is a constant. This last point is due to the fact that for any smooth periodic $\phi$, $\int_0^{2\pi}(u-\int_0^x v)\phi'dx=0$. (corrected after the comment)

Now obviously $\int_0^x v$ is absolutely continuous, as it is the integral of an $L^2$ (hence $L^1$) function. Note that this argument works for any $H^s$ function, $s\geq 1$.

There is maybe a simpler argument, but this is not trivial as you can only embed $H^{3/2}$ into $C^{0,\alpha},\ \alpha<1$, and unfortunately these spaces are not comparable to absolutely continuous functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which helps a lot. I am still confused about something: 1. how do you make sure $v$ is convergent? 2. I think $\int_0^{2\pi}(u-v)\phi ' dx$ should be $\int_0^{2\pi}(u-\int_0^x v)\phi ' dx$, and how to prove this equals to $0$?

Comment: When I check $v\in L^2$, I need to exchange the order of sum and integral,  I can't do that if $v$ is not convergent uniformly. For example, $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2 \log n}$.

Comment: The convergence of the series is an abstract but elementary property of Hilbert spaces : if $(e_n)$ is a Hilbertian basis of H, $\sum a_n e_n$ converges in H iff $\sum a_n^2<\infty$

Comment: Wow, I got it, thanks,